# Access the Window's DataContext from a DataTemplate in a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I use a DataGrid in my WPF application. It does feature RowDetails for selected Rows. Therefor I set the RowDetailsTemplate. Inside this DataTemplate i want to access my Window's DataContext. For Example I have a lable inside my RowDetailsTemplate and I want to bind it's content-property to a property of my viewModel which is in the DataContext of the window. How do I achieve this.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this usage of RelativeSource based binding, like `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}`. Here is example:

1. Xaml:

   ```
       <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
       <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="String" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type soDataGridHeplAttempt:ClicableItemsModel}">
                       <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding ClickableItems}">
                           <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                           </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                           <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                               <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                   <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                       <Setter.Value>
                                           <DataTemplate>
                                               <Button  Width="70" Content="{Binding }" Style="{StaticResource ButtonInCellStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                                        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.Command}" 
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content}"/>
                                           </DataTemplate>
                                       </Setter.Value>
                                   </Setter>
                               </Style>
                           </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                       </ListBox>
                   </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn>
       </DataGrid.Columns>
   </DataGrid>
   ```
2. View model:

   ```
   private ICommand _command;
   public ObservableCollection<ClicableItemsModel> Strings { get; set; }

   public ICommand Command
   {
       get { return _command ?? (_command = new RelayCommand<object>(MethodOnCommmand)); }
   }

   private void MethodOnCommmand(object obj)
   {

   }
   ```
3. Model pu this inside the the model class:

   ```
      public ObservableCollection<String> ClickableItems { get; set; }
   ```

regards,

Comment: Damn. Well, I did know about binding to a relative source and I also tried it but I forgot to write Path=DataContext.MyProperty. I just wrote Path=MyProperty. My bad. Anyway thank you so much for your help. I was going crazy about this problem.